# PayPal API: Created billing plans do not appear in dashboard

Tags: python-3.x, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I created a Billing Plan with the API endpoint like described in the [official api docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1). I create it by the endpoint:

```
POST: /v1/payments/billing-plans
```

I can now see it with

```
GET: /v1/payments/billing-plans
```

But it is not shown in my PayPal dashboard after login to PayPal in my browser. And the billing plans created in my django dashboard in the browser are not found by the API.

Does somebody have an idea what could be wrong? Or are they really separated? Would not make sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.

```
 /v1/payments/billing-plans
```

[is deprecated](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-plans/v1).

Just use

```
/v1/billing/plans
```

Like described here:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/integrate/

If you use one of the [v1 SDKs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/deprecated-rest-sdks/), you have to change the endpoint. Or use plain API calls, because the subscription api calls do not seem to be implemented in the [new SDK](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/) yet